# Is it legit to delete an answer even if the OP considered it helpful?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know if it is considered fair to delete someone's answer to a question on Stack Overflow even if the OP considered it correct and helpful by marking it as useful and upvoting it.

After a few minutes, someone replied the same way as I did but did not get the answer deleted. Instead his answer got accepted. I think that this is quite weird.

Comment: You should provide a link to the relevant question/answer if you want to discuss it.  As it is all we can say is that there was most likely some reason for deleting your answer that you didn't understand.  It's not like we can enumerate every single possible reason there might be fore deleting an answer.

Comment: It happened more than a month ago and I don't know if there is a fast way to find the link to the question/answer.

Comment: Why didn't you ask this question a month ago then, why ask it now?

Comment: Did your answer get deleted, or are you suggesting/asking why the other, later answer didn't get deleted?

Comment: My answer got deleted, I'm asking if it is legit or not.

Comment: Link-only answers might well be appreciated by the OP for example. But they are problematic for various reasons. As such they could be deleted even if helpful to the OP. Then there is blatant self-promotion. Helpful to the OP perhaps, but spam flags can happen. So yes, deleting answers can be entirely justified. Helpfulness to the OP is not enough. That said, without seeing your particular case, this is all guesswork. I don't know why your answer was deleted.

Comment: In short yes, bad answers will get deleted even if marked accepted.

Comment: Mh, I see. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you're referring to [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903400/external-storage-not-mounted/16903456#16903456), which reads:

> Can you append the java code to your answer? Maybe it's a problem of permissions in your manifest or you are trying to access the SD card while your phone is connected to the PC. In this case you are could not be able to access the SD card because actually is not mounted.

It was flagged as being a comment, not an answer, and was removed by a moderator as a result. The actual content that answers the question was in the comments on that answer.

When you flagged that answer for it to be undeleted, a moderator responded with

> Please edit the comments into the answer so that it actually answers the question without needing the comments.

which is exactly what you should do here. If you edit the answer to contain the solution to the question asked, as found in the comments there, flag it again and we'll be glad to undelete it.